# How to remove extra padding from listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I WANT TO REMVOE THE PADDING FROM THE LIST VIEW. I DID BUT IT DOESN'T WORK.

```
drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        // I HAVE GIVEN THE PADDING BUT ITSS NOT WORKING.
         children: [
          const DrawerHeader(
            child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountEmail: Text('swapnilmane@gmail.com'),
              accountName: Text('Swapnill Manee'),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/21/21104.png'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The drawer header also has a padding and margin at bottom. Please add margin and padding for drawer header and set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
drawer: Drawer(
    child: ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.zero,
    // You can simply use padding EdgeInsets.zero WORKING.
     children: [
      const DrawerHeader(
        child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
          accountEmail: Text('swapnilmane@gmail.com'),
          accountName: Text('Swapnill Manee'),
          currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/21/21104.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```